# Jest configuration error in React+Typescript+Webpack project

Tags: javascript, reactjs, testing, webpack, jestjs

I have faced following problem.
FYI, I am a beginner for the Jest, so please let me know what's wrong in configuring Jest.

`webpack.config.js`

```
...

resolve: {
  extensions: ['.ts', '.tsx', '.js', '.json', '.scss'],
  alias: {
    'webextension-polyfill-ts': path.resolve(
      path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules', 'webextension-polyfill-ts')
    ),
    reducers: path.resolve(__dirname, 'source/redux'),
    routers: path.resolve(__dirname, 'source/routers'),
    source: path.resolve(__dirname, 'source'),
    ...
  },
},

...
```

Here's the Jest configuration in `package.json`

```
"jest": {
  ...
  "moduleNameMapper": {
    "^reducers": "<rootDir>/source/redux/$1",
    "^routers": "<rootDir>/source/routers/$1",
    "^source": "<rootDir>/source/$1",
    ...
  }
  ...
}
```

But I got following error while run a test file.

```
Configuration error:
    
Could not locate module source-map-support mapped as:
/Volumes/WORK/Development/project/source/$1.
    
Please check your configuration for these entries:
{
  "moduleNameMapper": {
    "/^source/": "/Volumes/WORK/Development/project/source/$1"
  },
  "resolver": undefined
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue looks like from you set the wrong pattern for `moduleNameMapper`. The right one is supposed to be:

```
{
  "moduleNameMapper": {
    "^reducers/(.*)$": "<rootDir>/source/redux/$1", // You missed the 2nd part `/(.*)`
    // ...
    ...
  }
}
```